# What is the maximum amount of solutions to $f(x+1)f(x)= ax^2+bx+c$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recursion

$f(x)$ is going to be in the form $mx+h$ thus, $(mx+m+h)(mx+h) = ax^2+bx+c$. With basic algebra $m= \pm \sqrt{a}$. Also $(m+h)(h)=c$. I would guess that because $(m+h)h=c$ has two solutions max if $m$ is one number, there will be 4 solutions max if $m$ is two numbers am I right? I'm trying to find the max amount of solutions to $f(x)f(x+1)= ax^2+bx+c$

Comment: Is the $b$ in $ax^2 + bx + c$ the same as the $b$ in $mx + b$?  Cheers!

Comment: Not necessarily I should change it.

Comment: Note that if $a<0$ then there are no real solutions ($m^2 = a$ has no real solutions if $a$ is negative). Also we need something like $c = \frac{b(b - 2a)}{4a}$ to hold if $y = mx + n$ is a solution.

Comment: Saw your timely edit; well done!  I thus can with confidence ***endorse!*** your question.  Cheers!

Comment: In "$f(x+1)f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$", the "$=$" should be inside the MathJax tags, so you get a match in font size and proper spacing.  Otherwise you see $f(x+1)f(x)$ = $ax^2+bx+c$.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Since the expression:$g(x)=f(x)f(x+1) - (ax^2+bx+c$) is a 2nd degree polynomial, you can't get more than 2 solutions (assuming m and h are not function of x).